# cpコマンドのaオプションとpオプションの違い

Tags: linux, unix

CentOSの `cp -a` で指定ディレクトリ以下を全コピーしたら、パーミッションが一部変更されてしまいました。

具体的には、画像ディレクトリ内を再帰的に777していたのですが、一部が変更になったみたいでエラーが発生してしまったため、再度777へ変更し直しました。
`cp -a` でコピーすると、元ディレクトリ内容と全く同じになると思っていたので、かなりびっくりしました。
※色々作業していたので、もしかしたら何か勘違いしているかもしれません

**質問**
・`cp -a` と `cp -p` の違いは？
・`cp -a`のhelpを見たら、`--archive same as -dR --preserve=all` と書いていたので、`cp -p` を全て兼ねるのでしょうか？
・それとも `cp -ap` などと書くのでしょうか？

**最終的にやりたいこと**
・元ディレクトリと全て同じ内容でコピーしたいです
・構成も内容もパミッションもタイムスタンプも
※何もない場所へコピーする前提。コピー内容は重複しない、もしあれば全上書き

Comment: 実際に実行したコマンド例を書いた方が、良い解答が付きそうな気がします。

Answer (score 3):

http://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/GNU_fileutils/man1/cp.1.html
によれば `-a` は `-dpR` と等価、とあります。

オイラは先輩にディレクトリ構造ごとコピーの際には `cp` を使うな、
`tar` または `cpio` を使え、と教わりました。

`/home/alice/projects/zulu` 以下をまるごと `/home/bob/zulu` に複写するには
(書き込み先に書き込み権限がある前提で)

```
(cd /home/alice/projects && tar cf - zulu) | (cd /home/bob && tar xvf -)
```

`cpio` の例は他の人にお任せで。
今はもっといい方法があるんでしたっけ？

Comment: `cd` の失敗時に `tar` が実行されないように、
`(cd /home/alice/projects && tar cf - zulu) | (cd /home/bob && tar xvf -)` とすることを強く推奨。