# cp コマンドが -e オプションを使っていないのにエラーになるのは何故ですか？

Tags: centos, docker

※英語版においても同じ質問内容を投稿しています。

[why do cp command get error without noting add -e option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60519639/why-do-cp-command-get-error-without-noting-add-e-option)

### 前提：実現したいこと

Dockerfileを作成し試しにbuild実行したのですが、エラーが発生しました。
そのエラー箇所は「cp」コマンドの実行時になります。

### テストした環境

- ベースのコンテナイメージ [centos:7](https://registry.hub.docker.com/layers/centos/library/centos/centos7/images/sha256-1f832b4e3b9ddf67fd77831cdfb591ce5e968548a01581672e5f6b32ce1212fe?context=explore)
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)／OS: Mojabve
- terminal 2.9.5 (421.2)

### したこと

作成したDockerfileは以下のとおりです。

```
FROM centos:7

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk \
    SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/scala \
    SCALA_VERSION=scala-2.13.0

WORKDIR /usr/local/lib/

RUN : " *** nginx install ***" \
  && { \
        echo '[nginx-stable]'; \
        echo 'name=nginx stable repo'; \
        echo 'baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/centos/$releasever/$basearch/'; \
        echo 'gpgcheck=1'; \
        echo 'enabled=1'; \
        echo 'gpgkey=https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key'; \
        echo 'gpgkey=https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key'; \
     } > /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo \
  && yum install -y nginx \
  && cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service /etc/systemd/system/ \
  && systemctl daemon-reload \
  && systemctl enable nginx.service \
  && systemctl start nginx \
  && nginx -version \
  && : " *** JDK install ***" \
  && JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}/bin \
  && PATH=$PATH:${JAVA_HOME}/bin \
  && java -version \
  && javac -version \
  && : "*** Scala install ***" \
  && wget http://downloads.typesafe.com/scala/2.13.0/scala-2.13.0.tgz \
  && tar zxvf scala-2.13.0.tgz \
  && ln -s ${SCALA_VERSION} scala \
  && mkdir ${SCALA_HOME} \
  && mv ${SCALA_VERSION} SCALA_HOME \
  && SCALA_HOME=${SCALA_HOME}/bin >> /etc/profile.d/scala.sh \
  && PATH=$PATH:${SCALA_HOME}/bin >> /etc/profile.d/scala.sh \
  && source /etc/profile.d/scala.sh \
  && cd \
  && scala -version \
  && : "*** sbt install ***" \
  && curl https://bintray.com/sbt/rpm/rpm | tee /etc/yum.repos.d/bintray-sbt-rpm.repo \
  && yum install -y sbt \
  && sbt -version \
  && ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo /etc/localtime \
  && yum clean all \
  && mkdir -p /usr/share/app

WORKDIR /usr/share/app

EXPOSE 80
```

### 発生した問題とエラー

そしてエラーの内容がこれです。

```
cp: invalid option -- 'e'
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
```

今回のcpコマンドはオプション付けずに実行しているため
何故エラーが発生しているのかが不明です。もちろんaliasの設定は行っていません。

どなたかお分かりになる方、ご教示いただければ幸いです。

Comment: 本題とは関係ないのですが、`mv ${SCALA_VERSION} SCALA_HOME` は `mv ${SCALA_VERSION} ${SCALA_HOME}` ではないでしょうか(直前の `mkdir ${SCALA_HOME}` は不要のはずです)。それから、`SCALA_HOME=${SCALA_HOME}/bin >> /etc/profile.d/scala.sh` は `echo "export SCALA_HOME=${SCALA_HOME}" >> /etc/profile.d/scala.sh` ではないかと(`PATH` の設定も同様です)。

Comment: @metropolis さん レビューandご教示ありがとうございます！見直してみます。

Comment: 英語版での質問 (コメント欄) にて既に解決しているようにも見えますが違いますか？

Comment: @cubick さん　そちらは試したのですが他のエラー出まして根本的な解決に至らず。。

Comment: 試して別のエラーが出たのであれば、その新しいエラーについての質問を新規で行うべきかと思います。

Comment: 私の環境で実行した際に出るエラーは `Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted` でしたが、もし同様であれば例えば[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/31280/2808)などが参考になるでしょうか。

Comment: @cubick さん　マナーを知らずに失礼いたしました。他の方のコメントと併せ諸々対応いたします。

Comment: マナーというよりかは、今回の場合なら既に英語版でアドバイスのあった内容と同じものがこちらでも付く可能性があるので、把握している情報は常にアップデートして共有しないと質問者自身も「それはもう知ってます」という状況に陥ってしまうのは不幸かな、ということです (実際、774RR さんからの回答が英語版でのコメントと同じアドバイスにあたりますよね？)。

Comment: おそらく問題点としてはマルチポストと同様で色々とコメントが増えているかなと思います。質問者様は一度[マルチポストとはなんですか](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2418/)　あたりを読んでいただくと良いかなと思います。それを踏まえてどんどん質問してください！

Comment: 英語苦手な人がリンク先を読まないだろうことを見越して日本語で回答した次第。まあ `cp` あるある話っすね。

Comment: @keitaro_so さん　ご教示恐れ入ります。マルチポストという言葉自体を知りませんでした。。さほど考えずに安易にやってしまいました。今後はリンク先にあるようなポイントを参考にして質問いたします。

Comment: @774RR さん　ご指摘恐れ入ります。「どうせ英語版読まないだろ」のような悪意は無く、長い時間詰まってて解決せず焦りがあって対して考えずにマルチポストしてしまいました。今後はリンクにあるようにせめて4-5日回答を待つ等配慮を心がけます。

Comment: @yukihane さん　それも未解決でした、、ご教示のリンクで解決しました。ありがとうございます！Dockerfileで完結しないやり方を引き出しに入れました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

タイトルにのみ反応

通常 UN*X 系 OS では shell glob 文字 `*` をシェル (bash/dash) が展開した後に各種コマンドが実行されます。

```
$ cp * targetdir # は
$ cp file1 file2 file3 file4 targetdir # として実行される
```

そのため、次のような場合に操作員が期待していない意外な動作をすることがあります。

- `*` にマッチしないファイルは対象外 (`.bashrc` 等ドットで始まるファイル)
- ハイフン文字で始まるファイル名があるとコマンドラインオプションとみなされる

例 : ファイル名 `-e` また `.bashrc` があるとき

```
$ ls -a
-e  .  ..  .bashrc  abc
$ mkdir ../backup; cp -p * ../backup; ls -a ../backup
$ cp: unknown option -- e
```

ハイフンで始まる文字をコマンドラインオプションと読ませないためには `--` を使うとよい (`--` の後ろはコマンドラインオプションと解釈しない仕様) というのが GNU 業界では半ば常識になっているので

```
# ../backup が無い状態でやること
$ mkdir ../backup; cp -p -- * ../backup; ls -a ../backup
-e  .  ..  abc  # .bashrc は複写されない！
$
```

似たような話を出しておいた例
[1文字ハイフンが特別な意味を持つシェルコマンドの例を教えて下さい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/32124/)

ファイル１つのコピーなら `cp` で良いのですが、ディレクトリをまるごとコピーしたい場合には `cp -r` より `tar` や `cpio` を使うほうが安全であることが多いので注意しましょう。
[cpコマンドのaオプションとpオプションの違い](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/19554/)

Comment: さん　ご教示ありがとうございます！解決いたしました！大変ご丁寧に詳細を書いてくださったのでハイフンの意味がよくわかりました。

Comment: これからはコマンドを使うときはhelpにあるとおりにすることを徹底します。